# How to send back parameters from modal view in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a modal view that i use to log in users.I want to retrieve the user id from there to the view behind.I've tried with $state.go but didn't work.And using ng-href would be useless since it's not the same url set up in routes and i don't know how to do multiple urls per state

```
$scope.goToState1 = function () {
$state.go('details',{user: $scope.user, email: $scope.email});
}
```

and i just link it to the button using ng-click.what i want to know is how to send paramaters back
thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

If it's angular ui bootstrap modal we are talking about you can link your scope using the `scope:` option. Omitting some required options below for clarity. The `scope` option tells the modal to use your `$scope` instance from your controller.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
   scope: $scope
});
```

Comment: Iam pretty sure it's not bootstrap modal.I believe, to use it  i have to download it and i didn't.

Comment: I just saw your tags. It's Ionic. You might want to update your question subject to specify that it's an ionic modal view you are talking about.